# Upload Multiple Images and Insert Record for Each image path

Tags: php, mysql, file-upload

I am looking for a way to upload "Multiple Images" at once and then Insert Record for Each Image Individually. Right now i can only upload one image and its record getting saved smoothly into mysql.

I have been search Stackoverflow and Google as well, found some answer but couldn't make it work with my PHP Script.

**Here Goes the Form Which tooks necessary data from user:**

```
<form id="myForm" action="post_product2.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Category:   
    <select name="pcate">
        <option value="category1">category1</option>
        <option value="category2">category2</option>
    </select>
    <br />
Product Name: 
    <input type="text" name="pname" />
    <br />
    <br />
Description: 
    <textarea name="pdesc"></textarea>
    <br />
    <br />
Product Code: 
    <input type="text" name="pcode">
        <br />
        <br />
Price: 
        <input type="text" name="pprice" />
        <br />
        <br />
Offers: 
        <select name="poffers">
            <option value="New Arrival">-- New Arrival --</option>
            <option value="ON SALE">-- ON SALE --</option>
            <option value="Exclusive">-- Exclusive --</option>
            <option value="Featured">-- Featured --</option>
        </select>
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="file" name="file_img[]" multiple="multiple" />
        <br />
        <br />
        <input type="hidden" name="pdate" value="
            <?php echo $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');  ?>" />
            <br />
            <input type="submit" name="btn_upload" value="Submit">
            </form>
```

**Here's the code which processes the Form Data:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload']))
{
    $prodcat = $_POST['pcate'];
    $prodname = $_POST['pname'];
    $prodec = $_POST['pdesc'];
    $prodcode = $_POST['pcode'];
    $prodprice = $_POST['pprice'];
    $prodffers = $_POST['poffers'];
    $pDate = $_POST['pdate'];

    $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"];
    $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"];
    $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"];
    $filesize = $_FILES["file_img"]["size"];
    $fileinfo = getimagesize($_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"]);
    $filewidth = $fileinfo[0];
    $fileheight = $fileinfo[1];
    // GETS FILE EXTENSION
    $fileextension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $microtime = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", microtime());
    $filepath = "../static/products/".$microtime.".".$fileextension;
    $filepath_thumb = "../static/products/thumbs/".$microtime.".".$fileextension;
    $filepath2 = "/static/products/".$microtime.".".$fileextension;
    move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath);


    if($filetype == "image/jpeg")
    {
        $imagecreate = "imagecreatefromjpeg";
        $imageformat = "imagejpeg";
    }

    if($filetype == "image/png")
    {                                                 
        $imagecreate = "imagecreatefrompng";
        $imageformat = "imagepng";
    }

    if($filetype == "image/gif")
    {                                                 
     $imagecreate= "imagecreatefromgif";
     $imageformat = "imagegif";
    }

    $new_width = "400";
    $new_height = "400";

    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height);
    $image = $imagecreate($filepath); //photo folder

    imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $filewidth, $fileheight);
    $imageformat($image_p, $filepath_thumb);//thumb folder

$sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (prod_cat,prod_name,prod_desc,prod_code,prod_price,prod_offer,img_path,datetime) VALUES ('$prodcat','$prodname','$prodec','$prodcode','$prodprice','$prodffers','$filepath2','$pDate')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
}

header("Location: Dashboard.php");
die();
?>
```

For multiple files selections i made the input field as `multiple="multiple"` and set the name as array `name="file_img[]"` but don't know how to extract the array data to upload and Insert records individually. Pleas help

Comment: $_FILES["file_img"] will be an array of file do something like
foreach($_FILES["file_img"] as $file) { [...]}

Comment: didn't understand ...

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop through `$_POST['file_img']` as it will be a multi-dimensional array containing each file element:

```
foreach($_POST['file_img'] as $file){
    $filetmp = $file["tmp_name"];
    $filename = $file["name"];
    $filetype = $file["type"];
    $filesize = $file["size"]; 
    //and so on...   
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. After searching for the solution i know i have to loop the array, but don't know how to do that. and i've tried your suggested code but that doesn't work either and returns too many errors.

Answer (score 0):

You code can be refactor like this

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['btn_upload'])) 
{ 
    function deal_image($i) { 
        $prodcat = $_POST['pcate']; 
        $prodname = $_POST['pname']; 
        $prodec = $_POST['pdesc']; 
        $prodcode = $_POST['pcode']; 
        $prodprice = $_POST['pprice']; 
        $prodffers = $_POST['poffers']; 
        $pDate = $_POST['pdate']; 

        $filetmp = $_FILES["file_img"]["tmp_name"][$i]; 
        $filename = $_FILES["file_img"]["name"][$i]; 
        $filetype = $_FILES["file_img"]["type"][$i]; 
        $filesize = $_FILES["file_img"]["size"][$i]; 
        $fileinfo = getimagesize(filetmp); 
        $filewidth = $fileinfo[0]; 
        $fileheight = $fileinfo[1]; 
        // GETS FILE EXTENSION 
        $fileextension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION); 
        $microtime = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', "", microtime()); 
        $filepath = "../static/products/".$microtime.".".$fileextension; 
        $filepath_thumb = "../static/products/thumbs/".$microtime.".".$fileextension; 
        $filepath2 = "/static/products/".$microtime.".".$fileextension; 
        move_uploaded_file($filetmp,$filepath); 


        if($filetype == "image/jpeg") 
        { 
            $imagecreate = "imagecreatefromjpeg"; 
            $imageformat = "imagejpeg"; 
        } 

        if($filetype == "image/png") 
        { 
            $imagecreate = "imagecreatefrompng"; 
            $imageformat = "imagepng"; 
        } 

        if($filetype == "image/gif") 
        { 
            $imagecreate= "imagecreatefromgif"; 
            $imageformat = "imagegif"; 
        } 

        $new_width = "400"; 
        $new_height = "400"; 

        $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($new_width, $new_height); 
        $image = $imagecreate($filepath); //photo folder 

        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $filewidth, $fileheight); 
        $imageformat($image_p, $filepath_thumb);//thumb folder 

        $sql = "INSERT INTO `products` (prod_cat,prod_name,prod_desc,prod_code,prod_price,prod_offer,img_path,datetime) VALUES ('$prodcat','$prodname','$prodec','$prodcode','$prodprice','$prodffers','$filepath2','$pDate')"; 
        $result = mysql_query($sql); 
    }
    foreach($_FILES["file_img"]['name'] as $id => $file) {deal_image($id);} 
} 

header("Location: Dashboard.php"); 
die(); 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i ran into many errors after using your code.

Comment: The errors are as follows: http://pastebin.com/QhJiyxLw
(too long to be commented)